# Python. Почему при вызове функции выводится рандомная буква?

Tags: python

```
def find_missing_letter(chars):
    letter_lower=[]
    # ~ создание списка строчных букв
    for i in range(97,123):
        letter_lower.append(chr(i))
    chars1 = []
    # добавление данных аргумента функции в список, с преобразованием в нижн.регистр 
    for i in chars:
        chars1.append(i.lower())
    # нахождение точек среза в letter_lower по крайним точкам chars1
    a = letter_lower.index(chars1[0])
    b = letter_lower.index(chars1[-1])
    #  нахождение пропущенной буквы через разницу двух множеств
    c = set(letter_lower[a:b+1]) - set(chars)
    #  если первая буква аргумента нижн.регистра, тогда:
    if chars[0].islower():
        return f'{chars} -> "{c.pop()}"'
    # если прописная, тогда результат случаен:
    if chars[0].isupper():
        d = c.pop()
        d = d.upper()
        return f'{chars} -> "{d}"'

print(find_missing_letter(["o", "q", "r", "s"]))
print(find_missing_letter(["O", "Q", "R", "S"]))
```

Почему выводится рандомная буква из  среза letter_lower[a:b+1] при втором вызове функции с заглавными буквами?
Задачу решил, создав новый список для заглавных, но почему этот вариант выдает странный результат? Казалось бы - нашел нужную букву, перевел в верхний регистр.

Задача такая - Напишите метод, который принимает массив последовательных (возрастающих) букв в качестве входных данных и возвращает недостающую букву в массиве.

Comment: видимо у вас здесь `set(chars)` опечатка,

Answer (score 0):

в варианте когда функция вызывается с заглавными буквами, в вашем "нахождении пропущенной буквы через разницу двух множеств"

```
c = set(letter_lower[a:b+1]) - set(chars)
```

сравниваются следующие множества:

```
{'p', 'o', 'q', 's', 'r'}
{'Q', 'O', 'R', 'S'}
```

в итоге получается множество {'r', 'o', 'p', 'q', 's'} со случайно расположенными элементами.

```
c = set(letter_lower[a:b+1]) - set([i.lower() for i in chars])
```

это решит проблему.

---

и если я правильно понял условие, то можно сделать так:

```
def find_missing_letter(chars):
    return (set([chr(i) for i in range(ord(chars[0]),ord(chars[0])+len(chars))])-set(chars)).pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Код для нахождения пропущенной буквы в массиве. Нет никакой роли, возрастают или убывают . Данные помещаются в `set()`. Так же создается множество из последовательных данных без пропуска. Далее находится разница множеств. Можно написать короче, если пожертвовать читабельностью

```py
f = "abcdf"
d = ["O", "Q", "R", "S"]
def find_missing_letter(f):
    set_check = set(range(ord(f[0]), ord(f[-1]) + 1))
    set_f = {ord(i) for i in f}
    result = list(set_check - set_f)[0]
    return chr(result)

find_missing_letter(f)
find_missing_letter(d)

# OUT 
# "e"
# "P"
```